# Release mouse from Warcraft 3 windowed mode on Wine

Tags: wine

I'm playing Warcraft 3 - The Frozen Throne on Wine with windowed mode (Virtual desktop), the problem is that the mouse is grabbed on the window and I can't move it to the desktop or to other windows. With others games I don't have this issue. How can I solve it?

Comment: I believe this http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=906957 will help you

Comment: @vembutech The problem is not alt-tab, I can switch between windows with alt-tab without problems. The problem is that the mouse gets trapped on the Warcraft 3 window. I Googled the problem and I haven't found any useful solution.

Comment: How are you able to reproduce the issue?

Comment: When using Xfce I can get the mouse to release by using the window manager hide window key combination of ALT+F9